# Ubuntu 13.10: How to disable Nvidia graphics (nouveau)?

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, battery, nouveau

I have a **MSI GS70** laptop with **Ubuntu 13.10** installed. Unfortunately, my laptop has an **NVidia** graphics card, the only effect of which for me is constant fan noise, hot temperature of the laptop and drastical power drain (**powertop** reports 36–40W instead of [24W](http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/feature-msi-gs70-stealth-vs-razer-blade-pro-battle-slim-17-inch-gaming-notebooks/battery-life-power-consumption-portability-index)).

How do I disable this **NVidia** card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this: here is a [very nice guide](http://wenlong.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/disable-the-nvidia-discrete-graphic-card-in-a-nvidia-optimus-laptop/) on how to turn off the NVidia card. But **use it with caution!** When I followed this guide, I couldn't boot my system anymore, there was **Kernel panic**. But here is a workaround. Just change:

```
# echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

to:

```
# echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and it should work. At least it worked for me.

Comment: the latest version of bbswitch: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch