# Whole system freezes, even TTY does not work

Tags: 14.04, performance, nouveau

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and now after a while the complete OS freezes. I can't even go into TTY1 - TTY6. I have to use REISUB to restart my machine.

Most of the time, it freezes when I use Firefox (Aurora) and play some music videos and surf through the internet. Flash is not installed. Although it also freezes sometimes, when I do not use Firefox at all.

Are there any logs, which are helpful and provide them for you, since the reason for the freeze could be anything at all?

This is my hardware (hope it helps in any way):

- Intel® Core™ i7-3770
- ASUS GTX660TI-DC2-OG-2GD5 (no special driver is installed, just the default one)
- ASUS P8Z77-V LX
- Corsair DIMM 8 GB DDR3-1600 Kit
- Samsung 830series 2,5" 256 GB (Windows is installed here)
- Seagate ST31000524AS 1 TB (3/4 are reserved for files; 1/4 is for Ubuntu (16GB swap included))

---

**Edit 01:** Last time it froze, I watched a video and the sound kept playing, so I guess something with my displays; `LG IPS235P-BN` or my graphic card is wrong?

**Edit 02:** Seems like there is a problem with my audio settings/setup. If I don't watch any videos/listen to any music, Ubuntu runs like a charm.

---

When the system froze, I executed these commands from my Android phone:

```
sudo killall Xorg
sudo killall firefox
sudo killall chrome
```

But neither of those worked.

The logs from `/var/log/syslog` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/CmuxsLwv).

The complete `kern.log` file(1.4GB!) is filled with these 3 lines:

```
May 10 20:32:46 m01 kernel: [11846.172008] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP ch 4 [0x027f996000 compiz[2206]]
May 10 20:32:46 m01 kernel: [11846.172020] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] GPC3/TPC0/MP trap: MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS
May 10 20:32:46 m01 kernel: [11846.172030] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] GPC3/TPC1/MP trap: MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS
```

Comment: Could you check if there's anything useful in `/var/log/syslog`? The log contains timestamps so note the time before reproducing to easily find the corresponding lines.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen [these are the logs](http://pastebin.com/kNfvwf6r). I deleted the file and waited till it freezes again, so they should be pretty accurate.

Comment: can you ssh into the machine when it does this?

Comment: @crasic Do you mean to remote logon?

Comment: @Niklas yes, it will help determine if the system is still working but Xorg is unresponsive to your keyboard and your attempts to switch runlevels or is actually in a hard crash. 

If you can log in, you would also probably be able to fix it temporarily if you can log in and `sudo killall Xorg` to force X to reset.

Comment: @crasic I wish I could, the problem is that I currently don't have a second machine to test it with.

Comment: Does the system freeze if you use Intel graphics? Does it freeze if you use the Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Niklas can you run ssh on a smartphone? Also do you see any errors in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: @bain thanks for the idea. I'm able to logon with my android phone and execute commands using the terminal. I'll reset my kern.log and wait for the freeze.

Comment: @bain I updated my question, with the new logs.

Comment: Could you try Nouveau with a more recent mainline kernel or the latest kernel from -proposed repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: How did you run commands from your phone??!!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hit a bug in Nouveau. You can try updating to a mainline kernel ([How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa)), or install the Nvidia proprietary drivers ([Ubuntu 14.04 install NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)). It would probably help to get the bug fixed if you [report it to freedesktop.org](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Bugs/) or the [Nouveau mailing list](http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/nouveau).

Your system also has Intel integrated graphics, so another option would be to [disable the Nvidia card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413928/ubuntu-13-10-how-to-disable-nvidia-graphics-nouveau).

Comment: I installed the appropriate drivers from NVIDIA and let you know, how they work.

Comment: @Niklas Did the Nvidia drivers fix the problem?

Comment: Seems like it did, but I wanna wait one or two days more and see if really everything is okay.

Comment: just hit this bug, kind of annoying as I am only using the nouveau drivers due to a bug with the NVIDIA ones not allowing me to use 3 screens :(

Comment: @Horse Report it to the Nouveau project. The more people who report these bugs to the developers and help to diagnose, the quicker the bugs will be fixed.